# display views inline?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

so I was wondering what would be the best way to imitate html's display-inline on android views

let's say I have a layout that changes size and inside this layout we'll put dots(to represent views)... as an example

original layout

```
--------------------
|(-)(-)(-)(-)(-)(-) |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
|                   |
--------------------
```

after resizing layout

```
-----------------
|(-)(-)(-)(-)(-)|
|(-)            |
|               |
|               |
|               |
-----------------
```

as you can see the view moved to a new line...

is this possible in android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does not have a standard FlowLayout. I explain and show how to build one in this talk: http://www.parleys.com/#id=2191&st=5

Comment: thanks that's the word I was looking for ;) als thanks for answering :)

Comment: Error 404, I'll undo the downvote when you edit the answer to provide a valid link